# How do I use a 15vac output supply for 12vac output?

Tags: power-supply

I have a Christmas tree 12vac 10w light (MR11) and 12vac 2w synchronous motor assembly that I have lost the power supply.

I want to use a power adapter I have that is 15vac 1100mA. The light is too bright and the motor spins too fast.

Can I add a resistor or something? What value(s) would be good to try?

Comment: Can you crack open and rewind the 15 V one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resistor, I did this with a fan and it worked. you have to measure how much current the system use (I) at 12vac then you can add a resistor with 3/I ohms value. you have to also use a resistor which is rated for at least I*3* 1.5 power. otherwise it would get too hot. It's not an efficient way but it works. Your system needs 10w that means it needs 10/(12) which is less than the current your supply is rated for. You need to do a little calculations, but I guess a 10w 3ohms resistor could work. please let me know in the comments if you need more help with the calculations so i would edit the answer with more details.

Comment: Thank you very much, you and Rohka who also responded, were both right. I used a 3 ohm 10 watt resistor. It gets hot but not so much that it could cause a melted plastic problem. I ran it for 12 hours and checked it inside and out. The plastic was more hot from the halogen lamp than the resistor, however the combined heat was initially a concern. If I had a way to use the heat-sinked resistor I would have considered it. Wished I could post a picture of the modification for your review. Anyway, thank you again for very solid and complete answers.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is using a transformer with 0.8 turns ratio, but it's obvious that it's nearly impossible to find one.

Using a resistor to reduce the voltage is the cheapest but the most inefficient way.

So, buy a 220V-to-15V transformer (TX1) and connect its secondary to your adapter's output. You'll get 220V output from TX1. Then buy a 220V-to-12V transformer (TX2) and connect its primary to the output of the previous section. Voila! Now you have a nice 12Vac with minimum losses!

OK. Forget this. Just use a 3 ohms 10W wirewound resistor. Like this one: https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Dale/RH0103R000FC02?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvNd0dY0Kymznz%2fzbWwLvuhJozlzYjfVpI%3d. There may be excessive heat dissipation from the resistor. So you'll nead a heatsink.